# query behaviour of composite gin index

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.6

```
CREATE   TABLE products(  
    products_id serial,
    location_id integer, --(not unique)
    idle_products jsonb --has 1000 elements ('[13,45,8976.....]'::jsonb)
);

CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
CREATE INDEX idx ON  products USING GIN(location_id, idle_products);
```

Take just for example;

`products` table have  millions of rows and 1000 elements in every row in `idle_products` column.

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE   location_id IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(array[1245,456,6342,2,23453]::int[])) AND
        idle_products @> to_jsonb(222) ;
```

On that query what i want to learn is:

Is `idle_products`being searched through only these 5 rows by composite gin index and if so,  does that mean much more performance gain(because there are only 5x1000 elements in 5 rows in `idle_products` column, 
i mean it would only search through 5 rows using gin composite index) or is `idle_products` being searched through all rows in products table (despite filtering against `location_id`) and then reduce(limit) rows to 5
(`array[1245,456,6342,2,23453]::int[]` has 5 five `location_id`) by filtering `location_id`  values?

Comment: "I am gonna take 25 rows" nothing in that query limits it to 25 elements.

Comment: The wording of this isn't clear enough to tell me what you're wanting. Though I suspect it's an English problem.

Comment: @Evan Carroll i have edited my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see how the query will be run, you should put "EXPLAIN" before the "SELECT" and it will give you the execution plan.

There are three ways it could use the gin index:

1. It could look up just the location_id that you specify, then fetch those rows and filter out ones not containing 222.
2. It could look up just the idle_products you specify, then fetch those rows and filter out ones not containing one of your location_id list.
3. It could look up all the index entries for 222, and all the index entries for your location_id list, and take the intersection of those to go fetch from the table.

It will choose which of those it thinks will work better, based on what it knows about your data distribution.

Also, I don't find composite gin indexes to be useful.  Having separate indexes is more flexible, and PostgreSQL can still combine them (using BitmapAnd) when that is useful to do.  I'd replace the composite index with a ordinary btree index on location_id and a gin index on the array column.